# toggling between UIViews that have autolayout

Tags: ios, uiview, uicollectionview, autolayout

I have a screen with a 2 sets of buttons (both sets are inside a `UIView`) that only one needs to be displayed, and a `UICollectionView` below them (and tied to one of them in autolayout)

In order to "display" the correct view I'm using
`[self.view bringSubviewToFront:<relevant view>];`

Everything is OK until I go forward to a different screen and press back.
I'm getting a weird blank between the buttons view and the `UICollectionView`

It is definitely happens only after "2 replacements" (2 calls to `bringSubviewToFront`)

So my question is - what is the correct approach in putting 2 views in the same place and choosing the correct one when using autolayout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a container `UIView`, constrain it to the `UICollectionView`, and add the relevant button view as a subview of the container view. This way the only constraints you need to manage are the ones between the container and it's subview when switching. The collection view and the container view are always present, so only need to be set once intially.

You'll need to add the constraints in code when you switch the views in the container, something like this

```
// Remove the view that is no longer relevant, this will remove associated constraints 
[viewToRemove removeFromSuperview]; 

// Add the relevant view to the container
[containerView addSubview:viewToAdd];

// This constrains the view to all edges of the container
[containerView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[viewToAdd]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(viewToAdd)];
[containerView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[viewToAdd]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(viewToAdd)];
```

Make sure to keep a strong reference to both views so they are not deallocated hen removed from the view stack.

If you want a quicker way, I would just set the relevant views `hidden` property, instead of changing the order of the subview stack. I'd recommend the first way though, so you can be sure that the user can not tap a button that shouldn't be displayed to them